# How to create multi level menu in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-10

I am creating a multi level menu in Laravel from database records using DB Query. However I want to create a menu which is multi level. As of now want two level sub menus. But in future many level sub menus will be a possibility.
Expected menu structure is -

```
- Menu 1
    - Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 2
    - Sub Menu 2
        - Sub Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 2
- Menu 2
    - Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 2
    - Sub Menu 2
        - Sub Sub Menu 1
        - Sub Sub Menu 2
```

Please refer the code, I have written. Please suggest a better way to achieve menu structure using DB Query.

All menus (Parent Menu, Sub Menu, Sub Sub Menu) are stored in menu table only referencing parent_menu_id column for parent menu of each sub menu and sub sub menu.

I have written below code -

```
<?php 
  public function getMenu(){
        $mainMenu = [];
        // Get parent menus.
        $parentMenu = DB::table('menu as m')
            ->select('m.id', 'm.title', 'm.click_type', 'm.click_destination', 'm.ordering')
            ->join('menu_location as ml', 'm.id', '=', 'ml.menu_id')
            ->join('itemmeta as im', 'ml.item_meta_id', '=', 'im.id')
            ->where('m.site_id', 100)
            ->where('m.tenant_id', 10)
            ->where('m.parent_menu_id', 0)
            ->where('im.slug', 'top_menu')
            ->where('im.is_enabled', 1)
            ->get();
        foreach ($parentMenu as $parent) {
            $menu = [];
            $menu['id'] = $parent->id;
            $menu['title'] = $parent->title;
            // Get 1st level child menus.
            $subMenuOne = DB::table('menu as m')
                ->select('m.id', 'm.title', 'm.click_type', 'm.click_destination', 'm.ordering')
                ->where('m.site_id', 100)
                ->where('m.tenant_id', 10)
                ->where('m.parent_menu_id', ($parent->id))
                ->get();
            if ($subMenuOne->count() > 0) {
                $subMenus = [];
                foreach ($subMenuOne as $subMenu) {
                    $subMenus['id'] = $subMenu->id;
                    $subMenus['title'] = $subMenu->title;
                    $menu['subMenu'][] = $subMenus;
                    // Get 2nd level child menus.
                    $subMenuTwo = DB::table('menu as m')
                        ->select('m.id', 'm.title', 'm.click_type', 'm.click_destination', 'm.ordering')
                        ->where('m.site_id', 100)
                        ->where('m.tenant_id', 10)
                        ->where('m.parent_menu_id', ($subMenu->id))
                        ->get();

                    if ($subMenuTwo->count() > 0) {
                        $subMenusTwoArr = [];
                        foreach ($subMenuTwo as $key => $subMenut) {
                            $subMenusTwoArr['id'] = $subMenut->id;
                            $subMenusTwoArr['title'] = $subMenut->title;
                            $menu['subMenu'][$key]['subMenu'] = $subMenusTwoArr;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            array_push($mainMenu, $menu);
        }
        return $mainMenu;
}
```

This code is retrieving parent menus with 1st level of sub menus. But not retrieving 2nd level of sub menus properly. Please suggest how can we implement above code to get 2nd level or any level (1st level, 2nd level, 3rd level and so on.) of sub menus.

Thank You